# Inaccurate user location when map is zoomed out

Tags: mapkit, core-location

When I am completely zoomed in on the map the user location is correct but when I begin to zoom out the user location annotation moves away from its true position. For example if I set the location to Norway and zoom out to show Europe, I can clearly see that the user annotation is in Sweden.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView
        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            if annotation is MKUserLocation {
                return MKUserLocationView()
            }
            return MKAnnotationView()
        }
    }
}
```

Is the user annotation supposed to have such inaccuracy? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding the annotation to MKUserLocationView:)

```
return MKUserLocationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
```